# relationships as variable sets in c#

Tags: c#, tuples

I have an "employee" table. Employees have managers and these relationship is set in an "Associations" table.

I need to read all the hierarchies into a file. For example

Jack-sales rep, Jill - supervisor, James - Line Manager, Jacob - Director

To start with, I have read different employee levels in lists. For example sales rep list, supervisor list etc.

The next step is to query the associations table with the lists in the hierarchy order and develop sets.

For example, from the associations table match entries where the relatedkey is in sales rep list and employeekey  in supervisor table. Get this as a set of (sales rep, supervior) and continue querying the associations table with the last item in the list until all the lists are worked.

My trouble is I cannot find a good enough data structure to hold a variable level set. With every level of list processing the set should grow. Any suggestions?

Any alternate solutions are welcome. Note that the number of hierarchies are potentially big(could be a million) and performance is important.

Comment: if the problem of performance is in searching why not Dictionary...it provides fast lookups...

Comment: Does an employee should be under at most only of one other employee also, say his/her supervisor? If so, have you considered making a unary relationship rather than a binary one?

Comment: @Edper,  supervisor to employee is an one to many relationship. I did not understand your idea though.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need a data structure as much as a logical *data model* - you haven't described what the objects and the relationships between them are very clearly. (What's a "variable level set" for instance?) You're using an object-oriented language, this means you shouldn't be storing data in memory using tables, but as an object graph. Start by modeling your problem domain using an entity-relationship model, then figure out how to parse your input files into said model; instead you seem to be making the parsing step trivial at the cost of making the data manipulation confusing.

Comment: Millimoose, the problem in simpler words is , I have several lists(or any collection) of items where every list contains items in a hierarchy level. I need to find the relationships from this lists using an association table. I think the right way to do this is to sort the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Basing in your post you mentioned at least two tables that makes up that hierarchy of data, namely, employee and associations tables. So, which  means the degree of relationship is binary, that is, one table is related to another.

However, I think the best way to represent this is in Unary relationship, that is, an entity/table relating to itself. For example:

```
 Employee table:

 EmployeeID   Lastname   Firstname    AssociationID
 --------------------------------------------------
 1001         Smith      John         NULL
 1002         Moore      Steve        NULL
 1003         George     Gerry        1001
 1004         Bosch      Anton        1002
 1005         Mitchell   Marlon       1001
```

Because if your conceptual design is the most appropriate (not necessarily right) for your situation then it would be easier for you to implement code-wise.

You could for example create a `Class` with `IEnumerable<T>` to do recursive hierarchical joins
like this [one](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/recursive-hierarchical-joins-in-c-sharp-and-linq.aspx).

Or you could also resolve it on the back-end `RDMBS` first like `mySQL/MSSQL` before calling it in C# for example like this [one](http://addinit.com/node/23).

You might also want to explore a third party library that uses
Generic Collection like this [one](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/).

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your table and store everything you parse in a List> of the workers , whenever a new kind of worker level is found (manager / director etc) add that level as a new list of one of the primary list and the worker who has this level into that list you just created , at the end you'll have all the lists of all the different levels of workers and the workers themselves will be in the list of workers of the level you want...

(alternatively , you might want to use `Dictionary<string,List<worker>>` and have the dictionary's key be the level , so for example `SomeDict["Directors"].Add(ThisWorkerObject);` )